# Binding MicroCharts in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, charts, data-binding, binding

I tried to make a chart with MicroChart, by LearnTechnologies youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6xhZkJa7H4&t=1s), but for me it's not working. I tried to do it completely based on the video, but it still doesn't work.  In emulator the chart not showing.  I think the problem is with the binding, the MainPage xaml indicates that the {Binding LineChart} "No DataContext found for Binding 'LineChart'.
My code:

```
namespace MicroChartBinding.ViewModels
{

    public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase, IInitialize, INavigationAware, IDestructible
    {
        protected INavigationService NavigationService { get; private set; }

        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
        }

        public ViewModelBase(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            NavigationService = navigationService;
        }

        public virtual void Initialize(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
        }

        public virtual void Destroy()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace MicroChartBinding.ViewModels
{
    class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private LineChart lineChart;
        public LineChart LineChart
        {
            get => lineChart;
            set => SetProperty(ref lineChart, value);
        }

        private string[] months = new string[] { "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" };

        private float[] turnoverData = new float[] { 6010, 1000, 2524, 3245, 1245, 5767, 5544, 5242, 500, 1555, 400, 100 };


        private SKColor blueColor = SKColor.Parse("#09C");


        public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
          : base(navigationService)
        {
            Title = "Main Page";
        }

        public override void Initialize(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            base.Initialize(parameters);
            InitData();
        }

        private void InitData()
        {
            var turnoverEntries = new List<ChartEntry>();

            foreach (var data in turnoverData)
            {
                turnoverEntries.Add(new ChartEntry(data)
                {
                    Color = blueColor,
                    ValueLabel = $"{data / 1000} k",
                    Label = "trnover"
                });
            }
            LineChart = new LineChart { Entries = turnoverEntries, LabelTextSize = 30f, LabelOrientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
        }
    }
}
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:Charts="clr-namespace:Microcharts.Forms;assembly=Microcharts.Forms"
             x:Class="MicroChartBinding.MainPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="300,300,300">
        <Charts:ChartView Chart ="{Binding LineChart}"
                          HeightRequest="300"
                          VerticalOptions="Start"
                          HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
    </Grid>  
    
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Have you set the BindingContext?

Comment: Nope, just set the Binding in MainPage.xaml like in tutorial

Comment: You have to set a BindingContext or the Bindings won’t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you shared use nuget `Prism.Unity.Forms`, so you need to modify your code `App.xaml.cs` and `App.xaml` as follows,which implement the bind for the ViewModel and the page.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App 
{

    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer): base(initializer)
    {
    }


    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAppInfo, AppInfoImplementation>();

        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
             x:Class="ChartAppForm.App">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

And modify code in android platform as follows:

```
[Activity(Label = "ChartAppForm", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )] 
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        //LoadApplication(new App());

        LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }


}

public class AndroidInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        // Register any platform specific implementations
    }
}
```

**Note:**

You can get the sample of above tutorial [here](https://github.com/AlphaTechstudios/Xamarin-Forms/tree/master/Micro%20Charts) .

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml add:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MicroChartBinding.ViewModels"
```

Than after your closing brackets of the `ContentPage` add

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel />
</ContentPage.Binding>
```

Now you have a reference to your class and it should work.